# Android webview disable/hide keyboard on textarea fill

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

I have a webview and I am using "evaluateJavascript" to evaulate a script after the page loaded. I filling up a textarea, but the keyboard is allways showing up at this moment with an animation. (`javascript: document.getElementById('textarea').value)="asd"`) How can I disable that at all?

I don't need to showing up the virtual keyboard at all.

Answer (score -1):

In manifest.xml file write below code

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

And Activity write below code in onCreate()

```
try {
       InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) PickLocationActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(PickLocationActivity.this.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("HideKeyboard", "Exception = "+e);
    }
```

Comment: No I dont want to open it up when the focus on the webviews textarea

Comment: Read again what I want